# How can I make use of C# System.DBNull.value in Java?

Tags: c#, java, com

I'm translating some code written in C# to Java. This code uses COM objects to interact with a third party application. I managed to handle COM objects using *com4j* library, but one of the methods requires `System.DBNull.value` to be passed into it which is a C# object.

How can I handle it from a Java application?

Comment: I deleted my answer as I have no ideas if that didn't work :)

Comment: @durron597, that was a good try anyway.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with java but DBNull is equivalent to a VARIANT of type VT_NULL, so I suppose using com4j you can create a Variant (http://com4j.kohsuke.org/apidocs/com4j/Variant.html) call setType(VT_NULL), and pass this to the interop layer.

Comment: @SimonMourier, it worked! you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET `System.DBNull` is equivalent to a `VARIANT` of type [VT_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx). In fact this is documented officially here: [DBNull Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

So I suppose using com4j you can create a [Variant](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/apidocs/com4j/Variant.html), call [setType](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/apidocs/com4j/Variant.html#setType%28com4j.Variant.Type%29)(VT_NULL), and pass this to the .NET interop layer.

Comment: Works with using: new Variant(Variant.Type.VT_NULL)